# Symfony2 Doctrine MongoDB geoNear fetch records in ascending order on distance

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I am trying to list the records which are near to my search location. I am getting proper result. But I want to get the records in ascending order on distance. But I don't have distance property in my document.

Please help me how to do this.

My in put data is like

```
{
 "name": "xxxx",
 "address": "28 Acacia Road",
 "location": { "long": 83.2184815, "lat": 17.6868159 },
}
```

***NOTE :***  My document doesn't have distance property.

My query builder is

```
/**
 * Get nearby DOS  
 * 
 * @param integer $distance
 * @param double $longitude
 * @param double $latitude
 * @param float $earth_radius   | 6378.137 
 */ 
public function getListDOS($distance, $longitude, $latitude, $earth_radius)
{   
    $dm = $this->getDocumentManager();
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('ABCBundle:Document')
            ->field('location')
            ->geoNear($longitude,$latitude)
            ->maxDistance($distance/$earth_radius)
            ->spherical(true)
            ->distanceMultiplier($earth_radius)
            ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->execute()->toArray();
}
```

Thank you